# Drupal WYSIWYG using CKEditor vs CKEditor module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, wysiwyg

What is the difference between using the WYSIWYG module pointing to the CKEditor library and using the dedicated CKEditor module.

We currently use the WYSIWYG module with TinyMCE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer seems to be that with [the Wysiwyg module](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg), you get an interface for which buttons appear in the profiles, whereas with just [CKEditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor), you don't? Or at least it's not obvious where choosing which buttons appear happens in the CKeditor module. http://drupal.ckeditor.com/ has some documentation on the subject, which says you can change the buttons.

http://drupal.org/node/606404 for some background on why CKEditor and Wysiwyg are separate efforts (though you can use CKEditor just fine with Wysiwyg).

I'd be inclined to stay with Wysiwyg so that you can swap out editors (that is, the JavaScript libraries for them) without having to swap out Drupal modules.

Comment: **NOTE**: CKEditor is going to be in core in D8, and the project [CKEditor for WYSIWYG Module](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_ckeditor) has a D7 version. This project is likely to take over from others given that it is the future of WYSIWYG in Drupal, it is certainly the most active of the options (but still in dev)

Answer (score 2):

The CKeditor module gives you have much more granular control around where the editor windows appear, user role level permissions and the buttons available for each. The WSYIWYG API just allows for basic on/off configuration of editor windows for text fields across the whole site. Button profiles are based around input types (filtered & full HTML). The advantages of the API module is that it's not limited to just one editor (there's 10 or so) and really easy to configure.

The Ckeditor module is more difficult to configure and certainly not for most implementations, but very nice to have this module available if you require that level of control.

Comment: The ability to turn on the WYSIWYG per field is exactly why I decided to go with the CKEditor module instead of the WYSIWYG module (using the CKEditor JS library).

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, using the Wysiwyg module was a better decision.
In some special cases (mainly when the editing was inside of an Ajaxed page), using ckeditor was a bad chioce.
When using the Wysiwyg, replacing the editor itself wasn't a hard task, which solved several problems very fast.
Therefore, for future situations you might not even think of now - use the Wysiwyg module.

Answer (score 0):

Using the WYSIWYG module will allow you to fairly easily switch to another editor if you find one you prefer (or if new ones come onto the market).

Answer (score -1):

RE: WYSIWYG module using CKEditor library vs CKEditor module

I found the former only allowed the following toolbar;

[image]
<sub>(source: [johnathanthwaites.info](http://johnathanthwaites.info/sites/default/files/toolbar.png))</sub>

Later had much more like font colour, flash embed, spell check etc.

[image]
<sub>(source: [johnathanthwaites.info](http://johnathanthwaites.info/sites/default/files/toolbar2.png))</sub>

Have done a full explanation here;

Link to [CKeditor](https://web.archive.org/web/20170509000520/http://johnathanthwaites.info:80/Ckeditor)